# How to use a css stylesheet for only 1 React component?

Tags: css, reactjs, rendering

I am using a React Template, where i inserted a shopping cart site using some react and Simple HTML (The code is below the question). Also i have a index.css file, which contains the css for the shopping cart. My goal is to implement the css only in the shopping cart site.
I tried to "import './index.css' inside my shopping cart.
The problem was as follows: After rendering the shopping cart, the css was applied to every other site as well.
How is it possible to use the css code only in the shopping cart?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from '../../frontend/actions/cartActions';
import MessageBox from '../../frontend/MessageBox';
import { useLocation } from 'library/hooks/useLocation';


export default function CartScreen(props) {

  //  Namen
  var a = window.location.href; 
  var b = a.substring(a.indexOf("?")+1)
  const productId = b;
  console.log(productId)


  // redux store
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems, error } = cart;


  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId));
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId]);

  const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    // delete action
    dispatch(removeFromCart(id));
  };

  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    props.history.push('/signin?redirect=shipping');
  };
  return (
      
    <div className="row top">
      <div className="col-2">
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        {error && <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>}

        {/* display cart or message if empty */}
        {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
          <MessageBox>
            Cart is empty. <Link to="/">Go Shopping</Link>
          </MessageBox>
        ) : (
          <ul>
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.product}>
                <div className="row">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={item.image}
                      alt={item.name}
                      className="small"
                    ></img>
                  </div>
                  <div className="min-30">
                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <select
                      value={item.qty}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(
                          addToCart(item.product, Number(e.target.value))
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div>${item.price}</div>
                  <div>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="col-1">
        <div className="card card-body">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <h2>
                Subtotal ({cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty, 0)} items) : $
                {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.qty, 0)}
              </h2>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={checkoutHandler}
                className="primary block"
                disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
              >
                Proceed to Checkout
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple CSS files for different sites, did you think about further describing your CSS to also only be a part of a div class unique to this file? I usually have my outer div be something like `<div className='CartScreen'>...</div>` and then my CSS something like `.CartScreen .min-30 {}`

Comment: I have not. To be honest, i have poor experience with css. Do you mean i can grab all my css, put it in curly braces and mark it as .cartScreen{-all my css-} (the same name as in div)?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is, when you declare to which classes (or ids or whatever) a group of CSS (inside the curly braces) applies, you can include more than one class, and it will only apply the CSS if all the classes, including parent classes, apply. If you have a partial example of your CSS, it might be easier to explain.

Comment: body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
#root {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Layout */
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header'
    'main'
    'footer';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 5rem 1fr 5rem;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #203040;
}
(This is a small part of the css. The Whole class wuld have 400+ lines.)

Comment: OK, so for the first one, if the top div on your render return was what I mentioned previously, the CSS could be `body .CartScreen { margin: 0, ...`

Comment: Great! that one worked.
i tried it with this one: .col-2 {
    flex: 2 1 50rem;
  }.      it is called <div className="col-2">. However, here it changes nothing

Comment: Make sure they're in the proper order. Parent first, then child.

Comment: I got it! Thank you bro!

Answer (score 0):

1. import './index.css'
2. give the div in the html a specific name: `<div className="cartScreen">`
3. in css, specify the element where the style should be used:

   ```
   body .cartScreen{
       margin: 0;
       height: 100vh;
       font-size: 1.6rem;
       font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
       -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
       -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   }
   ```